# How to get a google sheets script to find the last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time trying to use scripts here so please help!

I have a sort script set up, however, I have data automatically moving to this spreadsheet based on cells values on different workbooks, which is constantly creating new rows. The current script I am using must have a range in order to sort, but that range is ever changing, please help me so every time a new row is added it will add this row to the range.

Current script:

```
SHEET_NAME = "History";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:V36";
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 25, ascending: true},
{column: 17, ascending: true},
{column: 24, ascending: true}
];

function HistorySort(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getLastRow` for that:

```
SHEET_NAME = "History";
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:V"; // do not specify the row here 
SORT_ORDER = [
{column: 25, ascending: true},
{column: 17, ascending: true},
{column: 24, ascending: true}
];

function HistorySort(e){
  multiSortColumns();
}
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var range = sheet.getRange(SORT_DATA_RANGE + sheet.getLastRow()); // change here
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

Comment: No worries :) If you find this answer correct, please mark it as correct or vote up

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact end result you are expecting, you can do any of the following:

**1. Adjust the `SORT_DATA_RANGE` such that you don't set the end row of the range.**

```
SORT_DATA_RANGE = "A2:V"
```

In this way, the entire range is being considered and even though new rows are added, these will still be included properly in the range.

**2. Make use of the `getDataRange`, `getLastRow` and `getLastColumn` methods.**

If you don't specify the range you want to sort since it ends up changing constantly, you can easily retrieve it using `getDataRange`. This method will end up returning a `Range` corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present. As for getting its exact dimensions, the `getLastRow` and `getLastColumn` methods are used.

```
function multiSortColumns(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastRow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = dataRange.getLastColumn();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, lastCol);
  range.sort(SORT_ORDER);
  ss.toast('Sort complete.');
}
```

#### Reference

- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getDataRange());
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow());
- [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastColumn()).